# Excel 2003 Spreadsheet saved with ActiveX disabled will no longer pop up prompt for ActiveX

Tags: excel, activex, excel-2003, vba

I have a spreadsheet that uses ActiveX. I realized that if a user selects **No** when prompted for ActiveX the first time and then saves the worksheet, the worksheet will never prompt for the user to enable ActiveX again.

However, the worksheet I am developing requires ActiveX to be enabled. So my question is:

If an user selects **No** the first time when prompted to enable ActiveX **and** saves the worksheet. How can I still prompt for ActiveX on the next re-open of the worksheet? In other words, how can I always prompt for user to enable ActiveX?

Comment: If macros are enabled, you could open a message box in the workbook open event.  Then, if they click OK, use send keys to open excel options.  This, however, still requires the user to know what to enable.

Comment: I think your only option is to put a disclaimer in the file that says ActiveX Controls have to be enabled for the workbook to work properly. Then put a little diagram that shows them how to do that, if they don't know.

Comment: Can you force user saying in a warning, that sheet will not work if they do not accept to install the ActiveX. When they say no, you close the sheet. Bomb! No-one likes such creepiness. So they will install it :) Whee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a login macro in my worksheet that would throws an error if ActiveX was not enabled. So, if ActiveX was not enabled, I isolated and caught that error and forced a save and shut down of the worksheet.

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  ' ...some code...
  On Error GoTo InitializeLoginErrorHandler:
    DoLogin

  Exit Sub

  InitializeLoginErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "ActiveX has not been enabled. ActiveX must be enabled for worksheet to function. Restart worksheet and enable ActiveX." _
      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "worksheet will now close without saving any changes."
    ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub

Private Sub DoLog()
  ' Login to system through linked .dlls and .ocx. This portion requires ActiveX to be enabled. 
End sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code of how you isolated the error? I may want to use this in the future